# Manifest Unresolved class MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, class, android-manifest

i have mixed two(A,B) opensource android apps together and i imported B as a module to A import was successful android studio automatically imported the project now i want to make MainActivity of B as a launcher app for both apps. i go to app A and in manifest in called MainActivity of app B like below

```
<activity
        android:name="com.app.testapp.new_files.ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
     
    </activity>
```

It does recognize the package but Mainactivity is RED and error says

> Unresolved class MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be you are not referring to the XML whole src directory.

Similarly, you can remove the following line from your XML

```
tools:context='.folderName.MainActivity'
```

Answer (score 0):

implementation project(path: ':B') worked for me.